# golang git pulling a repo

Tags: git, go, pull

I'm very new to golang
Im trying to do a git pull from go program. I have looked in to native libraries and found https://github.com/src-d/go-git/.

I has features to of cloning ect. but not pulling. Looking at the source it seems there is a function for pulling as well

```
func (r *Repository) Pull(o *PullOptions)
```

However compiler warns that its undefined. Can anyone point me how can I do this or to an alternative library which supports both clone and pull ?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You should create a Repository struct by cloning a repo:

```
import {
  git "gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4"
}

repo, err := git.Clone(memory.NewStorage(), nil, &git.CloneOptions{
    URL: "https://github.com/src-d/go-siva",
})
```

And then on the repo struct call Pull.

```
err := repo.Pull(&git.PullOptions{
    RemoteName: "origin"
})
```

You cannot call `git.Pull` directly.

Comment: Thank you, I need to first open the repo and call pull.

Answer (score 4):

`gopkg.in/src-d/go-git.v4` is no longer maintained recommended to use `github.com/go-git/go-git` instead. Refer - https://pkg.go.dev/github.com/go-git/go-git

Sample code

```
import "github.com/go-git/go-git/v5"

_, err := git.PlainClone("/tmp/foo", false, &git.CloneOptions{
    URL:      "https://github.com/go-git/go-git",
    Progress: os.Stdout,
})
```